# Time structure in linux mint

Tags: c, linux, time, struct

I'm newbie in `C/Linux` and I've one simple question. Consider the `sys/timerfd.h` header file. It consist the function definition:

```
   int timerfd_settime(int fd, int flags,
                       const struct itimerspec *new_value,
                       struct itimerspec *old_value);
```

I can't find the `struct itimerspec` declaration in the `sys/timerfd.h`. Where is this structure declared. I'm looking for header file.

Comment: If you want to know which header to `#include`, read the man page. If you want to find the actual declaration, `grep` for `itimerspec`: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55325/how-to-use-grep-command-to-find-text-including-subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

man (7) time.h

> The  header shall also declare the itimerspec structure, which has at least the following members:

```
          struct timespec  it_interval  Timer period.
          struct timespec  it_value     Timer expiration.
```

It's usually `sys/time.h` too.